# IllegalAccessError after moving from spring boot 2.4.6 to 2.5.4

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to upgrade from spring boot 2.4.6 to 2.5.4 and have started receiving following error

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
> re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2021-09-28 14:10:37
> [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'supplierInitializer' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/FunctionConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name
> 'inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider_integrationflow.org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0':
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'integrationGlobalProperties' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/integration/IntegrationAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties]:
> Factory method 'integrationGlobalProperties' threw exception; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration
> tried to access private method 'void
> org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties.()'
> (org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration
> and org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties are
> in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Not able to understand what has changed in spring boot 2.5.X , although upgrading till version 2.4.11 works fine.

Comment: Hi can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: You seem to be using Spring Cloud Stream. Did you upgrade its version at the same time as Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have an old version of spring-integration-core library. Delete all the folders under `.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration` That should fix it.